# Protecting database rows from manual modifications

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, digital-signature, x509certificate

I have a C# application that performs database transactions into a SQL database. The database should be updated from the software only, so i tried to digitally sign rows from the software using the following code:

```
  private static byte[] SignData(SignedData data)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;
        X509Certificate2 cert = data.Certificate;
        csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
        if (csp == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        byte[] hash;
        using (var sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
        {
            var vv = data.Data.ToList();
            vv.Sort();
            hash = sha1.ComputeHash(vv.ToArray());
        }
        return csp.SignHash(hash, null);
    }
```

And for verifiying the digital signature i use the following:

```
static bool VerifyData(VerifiedData data)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        if (data.Certificate != null)
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = data.Certificate;
            //var csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
            var csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
            byte[] hash;

            using (var sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                var vv = data.Data.ToList();
                vv.Sort();
                hash = sha1.ComputeHash(vv.ToArray());
            }
            return csp.VerifyHash(hash, null, data.Signature.ToArray());

        }
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Certificate");
    }
```

This code can detect manual updates in the database, but verify method takes too long time for big number of records. Any other ideas for protecting data in the database? or any modifications to this code to perform faster?

**Edit:** Also, the database administrator should not be able to modify data in the database.

Comment: Tag the dbms product you're using.

Comment: Can you remove DML permissions for all users except for the account using software

Comment: @TheGameiswar: i am searching for a software solution.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO this should be implemented using ms-sql security mechanism not by devicing your own. And SHA-1 can be mimicked by users so they can still bypass your reverse Turing test (machine only access)?
Next to that, you could ask whether you really want to check each row before/while each (long) query you execute. Maybe an update trigger checking consistency/authentication is then more efficient?

But the answer, to my opinion, is: make human users datareaders and protect the credentials for the machine user.

Answer (score 1):

This should certainly be done using **Security**, as that is what it is for. Rolling your own security layer is seldom a good idea... and as pointed out in your comments this is far less secure than using the proper security, and a very large waste of server resources doing something that is redundant if security is implemented properly.

You can generate a random strong password and encrypt it in the application, then have this as the only account with write access to the database. This is the most secure method and has far far less overhead performance wise since it is built into the database already.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189121.aspx